# jQuery Validation of another value failing.

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form that runs some validations.  One of them checks to see if a file is loaded in a field and if it is  a group of checkboxes need to be checked off.

my problem I am having is that my validations are only working if validation is triggered.
both FF and Chrome are not giving me any errors.

### here is the HTML:

```
<form id="supplier_registration_form" method="POST">

    <label class="block label">stuff:</label>
<br />
    <input name="referenceEmail3" id="referenceEmail3" value="" type="text" />
    <input type="file" name="file_upload1" id="file_upload1" class="fpp_textfield" value="" />
<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="agency[]" id="one" value="one">
    <label class="block label">one</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="agency[]" id="two" value="two">
    <label class="block label">two</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="agency[]" id="three" value="three">
    <label class="block label">three</label>
<br />    
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

## here is my Js validation:

```
$('#supplier_registration_form').validate({

    onkeyup: false,
    ignore: ":hidden",

    rules: {
        file_upload1: { required: false, accept: "|txt|doc|pdf|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx"},

        'agency[]': {  required : function() { 
                         var file = document.getElementById("file_upload1").files[0];
                        if (file.size > 0) {
                          return true;
                        } else { 
                          return false; 
                        }
                      }   
                    }    
},
messages: {
  yearEstablished:     'Please enter a year between 1850 and 2013',
  file_upload1:        'Only txt, doc, xcl, xls, ppt and pdf file extensions are allowed!',
  file_upload2:        'Only txt, doc, xcl, xls, ppt and pdf file extensions are allowed!',
  "agency[]":          'One or more certifying agency is required'
},  
onfocusout: function (element) {
  if (!this.checkable(element) && (element.name in this.submitted || !this.optional(element))) {
    var currentObj = this;
    var currentElement = element;
    var delay = function () { 
      currentObj.element(currentElement); 
    };
    setTimeout(delay, 0);
  }
}, 
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
  if (element.attr("name") == "agency[]" ) 
    error.insertAfter(".certifying-agency-error");
  else 
    error.insertAfter(element);
}

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the depends option

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#supplier_registration_form').validate({

        onkeyup: false,
        ignore: ":hidden",

        rules: {
            file_upload1: {
                required: false,
                accept: "txt|doc|pdf|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|html"
            },
            'agency[]': {
                required: {
                    depends: function () {
                        var file = document.getElementById("file_upload1").files;
                        return file.length > 0
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            yearEstablished: 'Please enter a year between 1850 and 2013',
            file_upload1: 'Only txt, doc, xcl, xls, ppt and pdf file extensions are allowed!',
            file_upload2: 'Only txt, doc, xcl, xls, ppt and pdf file extensions are allowed!',
            "agency[]": 'One or more certifying agency is required'
        },
        onfocusout: function (element) {
            if (!this.checkable(element) && (element.name in this.submitted || !this.optional(element))) {
                var currentObj = this;
                var currentElement = element;
                var delay = function () {
                    currentObj.element(currentElement);
                };
                setTimeout(delay, 0);
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if (element.attr("name") == "agency[]") {
                error.insertAfter(".certifying-agency-error");
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }

    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6Qwhw/)